# AzureActiveDirectory - Disable choose account

Tags: azure-active-directory

is there a way, during Azure Active Directory Login phase, to disable "*Choose an account*" to force users write credential every time?

Answer (score 0):

we don’t have an option to disable this, but what we can do is we can enable single sign-on with MSAL.js. Single Sign-On (SSO) enables users to enter their credentials once to sign in and establish a session which can be reused across multiple applications without requiring to authenticate again. This provides a seamless experience to the user and reduces the repeated prompts for credentials.

In certain cases, the application has access to the user's authentication context and wants to avoid the Azure AD account selection prompt when multiple accounts are
signed in. This can be done a few different ways:

**Using Session ID (SID)**
Session ID is an optional claim that can be configured in the ID tokens. This claim allows the application to identify the user’s Azure AD session independent of the user’s account name or username. You can pass the SID in the request parameters to the acquireTokenSilent call. This will allow Azure AD to bypass the account selection. SID is bound to the session cookie and will not cross browser contexts.

**Using Login Hint**
If you do not have SID claim configured or need to bypass the account selection prompt in interactive authentication calls, you can do so by providing a login_hint in the request parameters and optionally a domain_hint as extraQueryParameters in the MSAL.js interactive methods (loginPopup, loginRedirect, acquireTokenPopup and acquireTokenRedirect).

Here is the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-sso#automatically-select-account-on-azure-ad)

Comment: thank for your answer. I use _prompt: login_ to force users to write their credential every time. Here is the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)

Comment: Got it! if the above answer helps please accept it as useful answer.Thanks.